# generating a unique number of digits

Tags: java, string, random, concatenation

The codes below compiles fine but they don't generate the number of digits

```
ganerateNewRandom("aaaa", 3)
```

the result will be `aaa435`.

The codes below compiles fine but they don't generate the number of digits

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student
{
    private String studentId;

    private String name;

    private Random random;


    public Student( String name)

    {
        studentId = "UnKnow";

        this.name = name;

        random = new Random();

    }

    public String ganerateNewRandom(String prefix, int number)

    {

        int index = random.nextInt(number);

        return prefix + number + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main or from where you calling?

Comment: May I suggest a loop of some kind?

Comment: `random.nextX()` returns one number(can be any number of digits though).

Answer (score 4):

```
 public String ganerateNewRandom(String prefix, int number) {  //sic

    StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer(prefix);

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) ret.append(random.nextInt(1000));

    return ret.toString();

}
```

In the case you cited above, nextInt(3) will return either a 0, 1, or 2.  Nothing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The API for [`Random.nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) states:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

If you want to generate 3 random number, create a `for-loop` to append `n` generate numbers from `Random` and append it to the `prefix`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably worthwhile using `String.format` here:

```
static private Random random = new Random();

public static String ganerateNewRandom(String prefix, int digits) {
  return String.format("%s%03d", 
                       prefix, 
                       random.nextInt((int)Math.pow(10, digits)));
}
```

Note:

- The parameter to `random.nextInt` is the upper bound, not the number of digits. You need `10^digits` to get the number you want.
- Using `%03d` will pad any number < 100 with zeros for you.